# A go echo server using go channel, but no reply from the server

Tags: go, channel, goroutine

I am trying to use go channel and goroutine to write an echo server, but there is no reply from the server. The following server listens on port 9090, and create a channel `ch` to receive connection acceptances, then it pass to `handleClient` to handle the connection details. Is the following code wrong? It has no errors when under `go build`.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net"
)

const (
    CONN_HOST = "localhost"
    CONN_PORT = "9090"
    CONN_TYPE = "tcp"
)

func main() {
    listen, err := net.Listen(CONN_TYPE, CONN_HOST + ":" + CONN_PORT)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error listening: ", err.Error())
        return
    }

    ch := make(chan net.Conn)
    go func() {
        for {
            conn, err := listen.Accept()
            if err != nil {
                fmt.Println("Error Accept: ", err.Error())
                return
            }
            ch <- conn
        }
    }()
    go handleClient(ch)
}

func handleClient(connChan <-chan net.Conn) {
    var tcpConn net.Conn
    // fmt.Println("Accepted new client: ", connChan.RemoteAddr().String())
    for {
        tcpConn = <-connChan
        go Serve(tcpConn)
    }
}

func Serve(conn net.Conn) {
  // handle the connection
}
```

Comment: Your main routine exits. A server program has to live to handle connections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change your main a bit:

```
ch := make(chan net.Conn)
go handleClient(ch)

for {
    conn, err := listen.Accept()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error Accept: ", err.Error())
        return
    }
    ch <- conn
}
```

The for loop is the server's main loop and will run forever if you do not exit the server somewhere else.